# Puppet agent re-copying same file after every run

Tags: puppet

I'm writing a Puppet module that isn't working as expected.

Ultimately, I want to ensure that an application is installed and running on Windows servers. Puppet copies SomeApp.exe to a non-temporary location on the server's C-drive. If the app needs installing, it can install it using that exe file. Pretty straightforward.

It works, except every time the Puppet agent runs, it re-copies over SomeApp.exe resulting in a corrective action. I'm puzzled by this behavior since SomeApp.exe is already present.

Here is the code:

```
file { 'SomeApp.exe' :
path   => 'C:\Post\SomeApp.exe',
ensure => 'present',
source => 'puppet:///modules/app_test/SomeApp.exe',
}
service { 'SomeApp':
name   => 'SomeApp',
ensure => 'running',
enable => 'true',
}
package { 'SomeApp.exe':
ensure          => 'installed',
provider        => 'windows',
source          => 'C:\Post\SomeApp.exe'
}
```

It all works except it insists on re-copying SomeApp.exe over every time. The original SomeApp.exe has not changed or been deleted.
What am I missing here?

Update: It looks like it's not actually re-copying the binary, but it's still reporting a corrective action:

```
Notice: /Stage[main]/app_test/Package[SomeApp.exe]/ensure: created (corrective)
```

Thank you!

Comment: not familiar with puppet on windows; however this look like puppet is trying to install "SmoeApp.exe" on every run.  as such the windows `package` `provider` dosen't think that it is installed

Comment: As balder says, this is because Puppet has been told to install a package called "SomeApp.exe" but that evidently isn't the name of the package as it appears to Windows and Puppet, so Puppet doesn't think it is installed

Comment: ... and to be clear: contrary to your assertion, what you have shown does not indicate that the file is being recopied.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, all! Turns out you were all correct. The name of the executable in Windows is not necessarily the name of the package. I'm not Windows person, so I assumed that "SomeApp.exe" is the name of the package when, in fact, the name is "Some App".
It's working now, thank you!